# How to delete the selected input values

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, multi-select

I am using angular 6 application and i am trying to make a multiple select using input box **without** any third party plugin, jquery, datalist, select box and it is pure input box, typescript based.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="autocomplete">
  <input name="suggestion" type="text" placeholder="User" (click)="suggest()" [formControl]="typeahead">

  <div class="autocomplete-items" *ngIf="show">
    <div *ngFor="let s of suggestions" (click)="selectSuggestion(s)">{{ s }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  suggestions: string [] = [];
  suggestion: string;
  show: boolean;
  typeahead: FormControl = new FormControl();

  fieldHistory: string [] = [];

  suggest() {
    this.suggestions = this.users;
    this.show = true;
  }

  selectSuggestion(s) {
    this.suggestion = "";

    this.fieldHistory.push(s)
    for (let i = 0; i < this.fieldHistory.length; i++) 
      this.suggestion = this.suggestion + " " + this.fieldHistory[i];

    this.typeahead.patchValue(this.suggestion);
    this.show = false;
  }


  users = ['First User', 'Second User', 'Third User', 'Fourth User'];
}
```

Here i need to delete the selected values like the angular material chips, User is able to select multiple values but he also can delete the wrongly selected values.

How can i make a delete option for each individual items to delete the wrongly selected values inside the input box?

**Stackblitz** link with multi select option https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dndhgv

Any edit in the above link to make the multi select with delete option would also be much more appreciable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

component.ts

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  suggestions: string [] = [];
  suggestion: string = '';
  show: boolean;
  typeahead: FormControl = new FormControl();

  fieldHistory: string [] = [];

  suggest() {
    this.suggestions = this.users;
    this.show = true;
  }

  selectSuggestion(s,status) {
    this.suggestion = '';
    if(status){
      this.fieldHistory.push(s);
      this.typeahead.patchValue(this.fieldHistory);
    }else{
      this.fieldHistory.forEach((element,index) => {
        if(element == s){ 
          this.fieldHistory.splice(index,1);
        }
      });
      this.typeahead.patchValue(this.fieldHistory);
    }
  }

  users = ['First User', 'Second User', 'Third User', 'Fourth User'];
}
```

Html

```
<div class="autocomplete">
  <input name="suggestion" type="text" placeholder="User" (click)="suggest()" [formControl]="typeahead">

  <div class="autocomplete-items" *ngFor="let s of suggestions">
    <input type="checkbox" name='{{s}}'  (click)="selectSuggestion(s,$event.target.checked)" />{{s}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check and uncheck is not working properly in your solution.. For eg, if i check all four checkboxes, and if i uncheck the ```third user```, then ```third user and fourth user``` getting removed from the input box rather than removing ```third alone```... If it was fixed then it would be good solution.. Anyhow thanks for your time and help..

Comment: please replace **select suggestion** function. and i have updated above code.please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178581/discussion-between-shubham-chhapre-and-mani-raj).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a `selected` field for your `users` object, as following :

```
users = [
    {
        name: 'First User',
        selected: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Second User',
        selected: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Third User',
        selected: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Fourth User',
        selected: false
    }
]
```

The new html would be:

```html
<div class="autocomplete">
    <div (click)="showChoices()" style="border: solid 1px; display: flex">
        <span *ngIf="!selectedUsers.length">Users</span>
        <div *ngFor="let user of selectedUsers">
            {{user.name}} <a style="cursor: pointer" (click)="unselectUser(user)">x</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="autocomplete-items" *ngIf="show">
        <div *ngFor="let user of users" [ngClass]="user.selected ? 'selected-suggestion' : ''" (click)="selectUser(user)">{{user.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the .ts :

```js
selectedUsers: { name: string, selected: boolean }[] = [];
show: boolean = false;
selectUser(user: { name: string, selected: boolean }) {
    if (!user.selected) {
        user.selected = true;
    }
    this.selectedUsers = this.users.filter((u) => u.selected);
    console.log(this.selectedUsers)
}

unselectUser(user: { name: string, selected: boolean }) {
    if (user.selected) {
        user.selected = false;
    }
    this.selectedUsers = this.users.filter((u) => u.selected);
    console.log(this.selectedUsers)
}

showChoices() {
    if (this.selectedUsers.length) {
        return;
    }
    this.show = !this.show;
}
```

Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtcae2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: I couldn't find delete option in your solution.

Comment: You can delete by clicking again on a field. You could also do it using an icon which sets `user.selected` to `false` on click

Comment: User can delete any selected value inside the input box. Not by clicking the list shown below.

Comment: Well you should definitely use [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) as it does exactly what you want. See `custom tags` section on this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: That is what i should not do it as i already mentioned in question.. No library should be included inside the application..

Comment: Well maybe you should re-consider this choice, that I do not understand... Still, I will try doing something for you with :)

Comment: Updated answer and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtcae2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Is it possible to send the selected values from your solution on form submission?? Because on form submission i have to send the selected values.

Comment: Yes, you can access the selected values from `this.selectedUsers`. If you only need the names, you can do : `this.selectedUsers.map((u) => u.name);`

Comment: Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Angular developer, but i tried to do solution.
Chosen phrases from suggested are storing in "chosen" variable. You can type something and divide it by "," to store it in "chosen" like in angular material chips.

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1dt8fb)

Comment: I appreciate you for spending your valuable time and help as a new contributor in angular..